# keydown trigger css background color change

Tags: css, events, background-color, keydown

What is the easiest way to trigger a `background-color` change through a `keydown event`? At the moment I have it where when you press a key it makes a sound but I want to have it change the background color to something every time I push a key.

**Here is my JS:-**

```
function play(id){
    var audio = document.getElementById(id);    
    audio.play();    
}

function removeTransition(e) {
    if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
    e.target.classList.remove('playing');
}
function playSound(e) {
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    const key = document.querySelector(`div[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    if (!audio) return;
    key.classList.add('playing');
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
 }
 const keys = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.key'));
 keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
 window.addEventListener('keydown', playSound);
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

**JS:**

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", changeBg);
function changeBg() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```